# An Array returned by a model association is not an Array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

We have a model association that looks something like this:

```
class Example < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :others, :order => 'others.rank'
end
```

The rank column is an integer type. The details of these particular models are not really important though as we have found the same problem with other has_many associations between other models.

We have also added to the Enumerable module:

```
module Enumerable
  def method_missing(name)
    super unless name.to_s[0..7] == 'collect_'
    method = name.to_s[8..-1]
    collect{|element| element.send(method)}
  end
end
```

This adds a collect_id method that we can use to get an array of record ids from an array of ActiveRecord objects.

So if we use a normal ActiveRecord find :all, we get a nice array which we can then use collect_id on but if we use Example.others.collect_id, we get

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `collect_id' for #<Class:0x2aaaac0060a0>
```

Example.others.class returns "Array" so is it lying or confused?

Our solution thus far has been to use it this way:

```
Example.others.to_a.collect_id
```

This works but this seems a bit strange. Why would you have to do that?

We are on Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 2.3.4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Model associations are proxies, not just simple Arrays.

Instead of `example.others.all.collect_id` and your patch, I suggest you use `example.others.all.map(&:id)` which is the standard Rails and Ruby >=1.8.7 way to collect a single attribute.

Answer (score 3):

ActiveRecord associations lazily load the has_many records for performance reasons. For example, if you call example.others.count you don't need to load all of the records. Try adding this along side your patch to enumerable:

```
class ActiveRecord::Associations::AssociationCollection
  def method_missing(name)
    super unless name.to_s[0..7] == 'collect_'

    load_target unless loaded?
    method = name.to_s[8..-1]
    @target.collect{|element| element.send(method)}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Two possible solutions:

1) Extend a specific association:

```
class Example < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :others, :order => 'others.rank' do
    def method_missing(name)
      super unless name.to_s[0..7] == 'collect_'
      method = name.to_s[8..-1]
      collect{|element| element.send(method)}
    end
  end
end
```

2) Add the extensions to a module to get a repeatable solution.

Rails provides an option to extend the association array.

```
module Collector
  def method_missing(name)
    super unless name.to_s[0..7] == 'collect_'
    method = name.to_s[8..-1]
    collect{|element| element.send(method)}
  end
end

class Example < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :others, :order => 'others.rank', :extend => Collector
end
```

Read the [documentation](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) for more details. Search for "Association Extensions" in the page to get to the relevant section.

Comment: Ahh, I learn too much on StackOverflow.  This is sure to come in handy.  There have been times I wondered how I could extend the association between two models.  Freaking brilliant... Things like `@topic.comments.class` never gave me the name of the associative object, it always saw `.class` and translated to an Array before giving me the class as `Array` even though I knew that wasn't quite true until you tried acting on the data...

Answer (score 0):

You should use `all`

```
 example.others.all.collect_id
```